# How to put image and input box on same line in HTML?

Tags: python, html

On my main page, I have 
● the logo of the page
● an input box for typing a keyword string
● a button that submits the keyword

However, the input box and the submit button are both below my logo. ￼￼￼￼￼I want to put them on same line similar to Bing.

```
@get('/')
def search():    
    <img src="./images/logo.png" width=200 height=300 style="display:inline;">
    <form action="/result" method="post"> Hit Please:<input name="keywords"type="text" />
    <input value="GO" type="submit"  /> 
    </form>
```

I tried to put style="display:inline;" but it seems not helping

Comment: try <input id="test1" name="test1" type="image" src="images/f.jpg" value="myValue" alt="" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is enclose by form whose default property is block. So `display:inline` in your form also:

```
<form action="/result" method="post" style="display:inline">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply some styles to the form element. Add css properties  display ( inline ), width (by default it takes 100%). float (left).

**Sample code**

**HTML**

```
<img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="200" height="300" style="display: inline;float: left;">
<form action="/result" method="post" >
    <label style="display: inline;">Hit Please:</label>
    <input name="keywords" type="text" style="display:inline;">
    <input value="GO" type="submit" style="display:inline;"> 
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
form {
    display: inline;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    line-height: 300px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g13qo0va/